# Selenium Input text does not replace all the values

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, css, selenium

I am providing an input which is suppose to replace the old values at two tabs. The values are auto populating one at one tab but I am providing them completely without using auto populate feature. 
The value is getting replaced only at one tab and not at the other tab. The second tab shows the xml version of the first tab.

[Code of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hqq4n.png)

[Tab 1 where I am providing input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9m56.png)

```
 AllElements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='CodeMirror cm-s-
               codeedit CodeMirror-wrap']")
    for row in Inputs:
        Content = row['Content']
        Universe = row['Universe']



    for ele in AllElements:
        count = count + 1

        if count == 1:
            ele.click()
            #Content = 'TR.NetAssetEstBrokerName'
            driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].setAttribute("style", 
                      "visibility:visible")', ele)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = ' " + Content + 
                       " ' ", ele)
            driver.execute_script('return 
                      arguments[0].setAttribute("value",' + Content + ')', 
                                                    ele)


        if count == 2:
            ele.click()
            #Universe = 'IBM.N@RIC'
            driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].setAttribute("style", 
                  "visibility:visible")', ele)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].innerText = ' " + Universe + 
                            " ' ", ele)
            driver.execute_script('return 
                   arguments[0].setAttribute("value",'+Universe+')', ele)


    driver.find_element_by_id('button-1093-btnEl').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using `javascriptexecutor`. It directly changing the value from DOM. If you want your functionality should behave as per business logic use operation like setAttribute which can behave as required:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("YOURID")).setAttribute("value", "your value");
```